# How to Show ProgressBar over VideoBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, camera

I have a feature that allows a user to switch between the FrontFacing and Primary cameras on a device. During the switching process, I'd like to show a ProgressBar and TextBlock to the user. For some reason, I cannot get these to show up in the View, and the only thing that shows during the switching process is a frozen image of the nonrotated VideoBrush

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="68"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Center this on the screen --> 
        <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="videoBrushTransform" 
                                        CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>

        ...

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressBar x:Name="progressIndicator" IsIndeterminate="False" Background="Transparent"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="modeChangeTextBlock" Margin="12"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" 
                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void sensor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CameraType type = camera.CameraType;

        //Switch to other camera, if available
        if(type == CameraType.Primary)
        {
            if(PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true)
            {
                ShowProgress("Switching cameras");
                UninitializeCamera();
                InitializeCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
                HideProgress();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true)
            {
                ShowProgress("Switching cameras");
                UninitializeCamera();
                InitializeCamera(CameraType.Primary);
                HideProgress();
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    private void ShowProgress(String msg)
    {            
        progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
        modeChangeTextBlock.Text = msg;
        //progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void HideProgress()
    {
        progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
        modeChangeTextBlock.Text = "";
        //progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

EDIT * added below existing xaml code for testing

```
<Rectangle x:Name="cameraSwitchingFill" Visibility="Visible"
                   Fill="{StaticResource SelfiePageBackgroundColorBrush}" 
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressBar x:Name="progressIndicator" IsIndeterminate="True" Background="Transparent"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="modeChangeTextBlock" Margin="12"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" 
                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Text="test"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

The added edit is an attempt to see why the progressbar is not showing during camera switching. Setting everything to be seen on the screen, when first navigating to this page all I see is the `cameraSwitchingFill` rectangle, with no ProgressBar or TextBlock over it (although in the designer I can see these just fine). Upon switching the cameras, (as expected) I see the rectangle but no ProgressBar or TextBlock.

I then went back to not show the edits and modified

void sensor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Switch to other camera, if available
            CameraType type = camera.CameraType;

```
        if(type == CameraType.Primary)
        {
            if(PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true)
            {
                ShowProgress(AppResources.CapturePage_SwitchingCameras);
                cameraSwitchingFill.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                UninitializeCamera();
                InitializeCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
                cameraSwitchingFill.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                HideProgress();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true)
            {
                ShowProgress(AppResources.CapturePage_SwitchingCameras);
                cameraSwitchingFill.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                UninitializeCamera();
                InitializeCamera(CameraType.Primary);
                cameraSwitchingFill.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                HideProgress();
            }
        }
    }
```

So the results are when I permanently make the rectangle and Progressbar show on the screen, Only the rectangle is shown until the first camera switch click event occurs, and thereafter neither the rectangle or progressbar will show. Also, the frozen image remains on the screen during the switching even though the rectangle and progressbar, declared below the videobrush implementation in xaml, are set to visible during this time.

Comment: this is just an idea - you can use overlay

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you. try this

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>                    
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <!-- Center this on the screen -->
                    <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" >
                                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="videoBrushTransform" 
                                                    CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            </VideoBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                    </Canvas>
              <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <TextBlock x:Name="modeChangeTextBlock" Margin="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
         <ProgressBar x:Name="progressIndicator" IsIndeterminate="False" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
           </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Maybe you could offer some suggestions based on my edits?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the declarations. Its just that the order at which you are making the declarations isnt correct.

the overlapping in grid is done by the order at which you write your xaml

In the xaml given the Panel containing textblock and progressbar is placed at first position and then the panel containing the Videobrush comes which overlaps the first panel(The main reason behind the invisibility). So, if you want the panel to be visible just declare it one level below the panel containing the videobrush. This woulf help the panel having progressbar to overlap the panel containing the videobrush.

and hence the updated declarations now becomes

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="68"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Center this on the screen -->


            <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" >
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="videoBrushTransform" 
                                        CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressBar x:Name="progressIndicator" IsIndeterminate="True" Background="Transparent"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="modeChangeTextBlock" Margin="12" Text="loading"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" 
                   Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is actually how I had my declarations at first, but nothing worked. I switched it back to how you stated though. I've noticed when switching between the cameras, once the button is pressed and during the time when one camera is uninitialized and the other is initialized, a frozen image of the nonrotated VideoBrush is shown on the screen. I wouldn't think this would be overlapping the StackPanel with the ProgressBar and TextBlock with your implementation, but I'm not seeing anything on the screen.

Comment: Okay its strange, Then try calling HideProgress() on photocamera object's initialized event.(Assuming that there is no xaml re positioning in UninitializeCamera(), InitializeCamera())

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either. I am centering the VideoCanvas in xaml though because it is not centered otherwise when rotating the videobrush.